# With blocks to make implicit methods in ruby

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, capybara

folks, I have a lot of code like this

```
Thread.new do
    puts "thread start"
    browser = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
    browser.visit "http://www.google.com/"
    browser.click "Search"
end
```

I'm trying to make it so that I don't have to specify browser.
every time I call its methods. (make it implicit)

```
Thread.new do
    with browser do
        puts "thread start"
        browser = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
        browser.visit "http://www.google.com/"
        browser.click "Search"
    end
end
```

How can I make it work?

I think visual basic has something similar in [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
Thread.new do
  puts "thread start"

  Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist).instance_eval do
    visit "http://www.google.com/"
    click "Search"
  end
end
```